# The growth rate of the group $\mathbb{Z}[1/2] \rtimes _\phi \mathbb{Z}$, where $\phi (1)$ corresponds to multiplying every number by $2$

Tags: gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, geometric-group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

Consider the group $G = \mathbb{Z}[1/2] \rtimes _\phi \mathbb{Z}$, where $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]  = \{j/2^m \mid j \in \mathbb{Z}, m\in\mathbb{N}  \}$, the dyadic rationals, and for every $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, $\phi (n)$  acts on $\mathbb{Z}[1/2] $ by multiplying every number by $2^n$.

It is known that $G$ has exponential growth, and is generated by $S = \{(1,0), (0,1)\}$, hence we have the trivial upper bound for the growth function $\mid B_S(n)\mid \leq 3^n$.

**Question**: Is there a better known ***upper bound*** for the growth function?

Any reference would be really appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: See eg Theorem 5.5 and Table 1 of this paper.  https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.14534

Comment: It is often referred to as Baumslag-Solitar group $\mathrm{BS}(1,2)$, although it might predate the Baumslag-Solitar paper with no specific names (it was certainly known to Ph. Hall and Higman in the 50s).

Comment: Thank you both for your help!